# Customise switch appearance in AndroidX preference activity

Tags: android, android-xml, android-resources, androidx, android-preferences

**Summary:** How do I customise/style the colour and appearance of AndroidX switch preferences?

**Detail:** Simplifying a bit, I have an Android app that uses the AndroidX preference classes. My preference activity inherits from `AppCompatActivity` and creates a minimal fragment that derives from `PreferenceFragmentCompat`. In my `preferences.xml` I have a switch preference:

```
<SwitchPreferenceCompat
    android:key="@string/soundOnKey"
    android:title="@string/soundOnTitle"
    android:summary="@string/soundOnSummary"/>
```

In my `styles.xml` I have a style:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Settings" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I apply this theme in my preference activity's `OnCreate()`. This all works as expected.

**Question:** How do I extend my settings style xml to specify colours for the "thumb" and "slide" parts of the switch that controls the "sound on" preference?

Thanks.